# How to call static class method from string?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

Excuse my ignorance/mistake as I'm a newbie and learning. I have a static class with the name of the country, `Finland`, as seen below.

```
namespace Countries
{
    public static class Finland
    {
        public static int ID { get; set; } = 7;
        public static string nameOfCountry { get; set; } = "Finland";
        public static string abbreviation { get; set; } = "FI";
        public static string flagLocation { get; set; } = "finishFlag.png";
        public static string GetFlag()
        {
            return "finishFlag.png";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using HttpClient to do GET request a JSON string from a website. Then I use DeserializeObject to deserialize JSON to an object. One of the variables of the object is `string countryName` (which exactly matches the string, nameOfCountry). By using this string (countryName), I want to call the `GetFlag()` method from the respective country class. However, I don't know how to call this static method from the string `countryName`. I can compare `nameOfCountry` string in with the `countryName` string, however I have 24 country classes like the class `Finland` which means 24 if else if statements.

I saw the `Type.GetType()` method from one of the answers in StackOverflow but I didn't understand how this can be used here as I'm not creating a instance. Please provide an example to solution so that it's easier to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using a static class here?  Why do you need to compare the strings if each country has its own GetFlag() method?

Comment: You'd have to use reflection which is expensive.  Instead create a country class then generate objects of that class for your countries and put them into a `Dictionary<string, Country>` then you can use you're string value to lookup the corresponding country.

Comment: @maccettura I thought using static class would be better in my case since I'm using these classes several times in different parts of the app and instead of creating an instance every time, it would be better both memory and efficiency wise.

Comment: @cptalpdeniz You can make the instances of a class static and thus use about the same space and not have to create them multiple times.

Comment: @cptalpdeniz - you can create an instance per country, once, and keep re-using those instances.

Comment: @juharr and antiduh, I didn't know this was possible. I will try and see how it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need 24 different classes, you need 1 class with 24 instances.

```
public class Country
{
    public int ID { get; }
    public string NameOfCountry { get; }
    public string Abbreviation { get; }
    public string FlagLocation { get; }

    public Country(int id, string nameOfCountry, string abbreviation, string flagLocation)
    {
        ID = id;
        NameOfCountry = nameOfCountry;
        Abbreviation = abbreviation;
        FlagLocation = flagLocation;
    }        
}
```

Notice that if those properties were `static` as in the question, all instances would share the value, which is something you don't want here.

The best way to store these classes (assuming you cannot use a database) would be to use a Dictionary:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Country> _countries = new Dictionary<string, Country>
{
    ["Finland"] = new Country(7, "Finland", "FI", "finishFlag.png"),
    ["USA"] = ...
};
```

You can then access these countries by their name:

```
Country country = _countries["Finland"];
```

Adding countries to the dictionary is then much easier than creating a new class and adding a new `if` case.

Comment: `["Finland"] = new Country(7, "Finland", "FI", "finishFlag.png"),` is a bad case of Dont Repeat Yourself. Instantiate the object by hardcoding the values once, then use the instantiated object to add to the map. Prevents you from doing `["Filand"] = new Country( "Finland", ... )`.

Comment: @antiduh I'm not sure how much that'd help if you still need to hardcode 24 different cases. Mind to expand a little?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I think he means to use Country.NameOfCountry as the key when adding to the dictionary instead of duplicating the magic string constant in both the dictionary key and the constructor.

Comment: @Dan In production code I'd promote that to a constant and then the reuse shouldn't be a big deal, but then this is mostly about the OP not creating a bunch of static classes.

Comment: @antiduh: On the other hand, even DRY won't save you from "finish" vs "Finnish".  (and neither will a spell-checker)

Answer (score 3):

Don't create a bunch of static classes.  Instead create one Country class then create objects of each country.

```
public class Country
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public tring Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public tring FlagLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can have a static dictionary

```
public static Dictionary<string, Country> Countries = 
{
    ["Finland"] = new Country
    {
        ID = 7,
        Name = "Finland",
        Abbreviation = "FI",
        FlagLocation = "finishFlag.png"
    },
    ["Germany"] = new Country
    {
        ID = 8,
        Name = "Germany",
        Abbreviation = "DE",
        FlagLocation = "germanFlag.png"
    }
}
```

Then given the name of a country you can get the flag location like this

```
Countries["Finland"].FlagLocation;
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Copy and paste gets you ever time.

Answer (score 1):

If you use only static classes, you cannot rely on any common structure between classes (static classes cannot participate in polymorphism).

Instead, what if you defined your countries using an interface, and somewhere in your code you initialized a singleton instance of each of your country types? Then, when you get a string back, you could search for the instance that has the right country name, and use the rest of the information as you see fit.

As an alternative to @juharr's reply, you could use an interface, and then have each country implement that interface as a dedicated class; this lets you have country-specific behavior, if you were to find that you need it. If you don't, then @juharr's answer is effective.

```
public interface ICountry
{
    int Id { get; }

    string Name { get; }

    // .. and so on.
}

public class Finland : ICountry
{
    public string Name { get; private set; } = "Finland";

    public int Id { get; private set; } = 7;
}

public class CountryRegistry
{
    private Dictionary<string, ICountry> countryMap;

    public CountryRegistry()
    {
        this.countryMap = new Dictionary<string, ICountry>();

        InitCountries();
    }

    public ICountry FindByName( string searchName )
    {
        ICountry result;
        if( this.countryMap.TryGetValue( searchName, out result ) )
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void InitCountries()
    {
        AddCountryToMap( new Finland() );
        // .. and so on
    }

    private void AddCountryToMap( ICountry country )
    {
        this.countryMap.Add( country.Name, country );
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the OP is new to C# I would call this option the most confusing of all suggestions. Especially since his call seems to come from a http request, it doesn't seem to be very effective. But seeing this code makes me think how much easier live gets with auto properties and `TryGetValue` with `out var result` declaration (though you really don't need the else block there

Answer (score 1):

declaring an object as a class is not common in programmer's world. class is somewhere to define a template (and a collection of behaviors). you can define country class in this way:

```
public class Country    
{
    public int ID { get; set; };
    public string NameOfCountry { get; set; };
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; };
    public string FlagLocation { get; set; };
}
```

and then define your countries as static objects:

```
 static Country Finland = new Country() { ID = 7, 
                                          NameOfCountry="Finland",
                                          Abbreviation  = "FI",
                                          FlagLocation = "finishFlag.png"
                                         };
```